# Java ClassLoader Not Finding Expected Resource

Tags: java, netbeans, classpath, classloader

I have a jar file that contains the following:

```
LibJar Contents

dir1
   |dir1-1
   |     |Class1-1-1
   |     |LClass1-1-2
   |Ldir1-2
         |LClass1-2-1
Ldir2
   |LClass2-1
```

My java program (we can call it ProgJar, but I also run it in Netbeans IDE) has the following package structure:

```
ProgJar

dir1
   |dir1-1
   |     |Class-1-1
   |     |PClass1-1-2        Different file name from LibJar
Pdir2
   |PClass2-1
```

The only shared package structure between ProgJar and LibJar is "dir1/dir1-1/Class1-1-1". Everything else prefixed with a P is unique to ProgJar and everything prefixed with a L is unique to LibJar.

I use LibJar as a library in ProgJar.

This is the snippet of code I run in ProjJar:

```
ClassLoader clP = Pdir2.PClass2-1.class.getClassLoader();
ClassLoader clL = Ldir2.LClass2-1.class.getClassLoader();

URL u1 = clP.getResource("dir1/dir1-1");
URL u2 = clL.getResource("dir1/dir1-1");

System.out.printf(u1.toExternalForm());
System.out.printf(u2.toExternalForm());
```

When I run this in Netbeans I get the following output:

```
Netbeans Output:
jar:file:/C:/path/to/project/lib/LibJar.jar!/dir1/dir1-1
jar:file:/C:/path/to/project/lib/LibJar.jar!/dir1/dir1-1
```

When I run as a ProgJar as a built jar outside of netbeans, I get:

```
Jar Output:
jar:file:/C:/path/to/ProgJar/ProgJar.jar!/dir1/dir1-1
jar:file:/C:/path/to/ProgJar/ProgJar.jar!/dir1/dir1-1
```

What I expect to see is the following:

```
Netbeans Output:
jar:file:/C:/path/to/project/build/classes/dir1/dir1-1
jar:file:/C:/path/to/project/lib/LibJar.jar!/dir1/dir1-1

Jar Output:
jar:file:/C:/path/to/ProgJar/ProgJar.jar!/dir1/dir1-1
jar:file:/C:/path/to/ProgJar/libs/LibJar.jar!/dir1/dir1-1
```

I read through a few different articles, but this one seems somewhat relevant to this particular issue:

http://jeewanthad.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-solve-java-classpath-hell-with.html

How am I able to achieve my specified output?

Answer (score 1):

Below code is not doing what you are expecting it to do:

```
ClassLoader clP = Pdir2.PClass2-1.class.getClassLoader();
ClassLoader clL = Ldir2.LClass2-1.class.getClassLoader();
```

Here clP amd clL are same Classloader instances(you system/application classloader to be specific).To verify, just see `(clP == clL)` should return true.

What you want to do is, use a custom classloader(URLClassLoader should do) to load your library. Then, **the system classloader that loaded your ProgJar and your custom classloader will be different.** Then rest of your code should work as expected.

Comment: I will give this a try and report back.

Comment: Any progress on your problem?

Comment: I haven't got around to trying this out yet. I will try to get to it this week.